# prolog 4 QUEENS PROBLEM helps giving error not able to find it

Tags: prolog

```
perm([X|Y],Z):-perm(Y,W),delete_member(X,Z,W).
perm([],[]).

delete_member(X,[X|R],R).
delete_member(X,[F|R],[F|S]):-delete_member(X,R,S).

solve(P):-
    perm([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],P),
    combine([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],P,S,D),
    all_diff(S),
    all_diff(D).

combine([X1|X],[Y1|Y],[S1|S],[D1|D]):-
       S1 is X1+Y1,
       D1 is X1-Y1,
       combine(X,Y,S,D).
combine([],[],[],[]).

all_diff([X|Y]):-\+member(X,Y),all_diff(Y).
all_diff([X]).

?- solve(P).
?- setof(P,solve(P),set),length(set,L).
```

giving error,not able to find it please help

Comment: How do you run this code? What kind of error does it give? What is it supposed to do? Where have you searched before giving up?

Comment: Youtube video which contains and explains this code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypPLkiVsMDc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: try `setof(P,solve(P),_Set),length(_Set,L).`

Comment: What error is it giving? Have you tested the delete_member and perm functions and are sure they work?